# Scripting VirtualBox and VM Image Directory?

Tags: shell, virtualbox

I run a script from my desktop that creates virtual machines as needed (its shown below).

When the script executes from my desktop (almost always the case), the VM (`<name>.vbox`) is saved to `~/VirtualBox VMs/<name>` but the hard drive (`<name>.vdi`) is saved to my desktop. I then have to move the hard drive and fixup the location in the `*.vbox` file.

`VBoxManage showvminfo` does not provide the directory location (though it could probably be parsed from a related field).

`VBoxManage` has a `setproperty` that offers a `machinefolder`, but it does not have a corresponding `getproperty`. Calling `VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder` (with no arguments) results in an error.

How does one get the directory used by `VBoxManage` for saving the virtual machine?

```
MEDIA=ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64.iso
VMNAME=openstack-swift-2
VMOSTYPE=Ubuntu_64

##########################################
# Public network vboxnet0 (10.1.0.0/16)
VBoxManage hostonlyif create
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 10.1.0.254 --netmask 255.255.0.0

##########################################
# Private network vboxnet1 (10.2.0.0/16)
VBoxManage hostonlyif create
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet1 --ip 10.2.0.254 --netmask 255.255.0.0

##########################################
# VirtualBox Machine
VBoxManage createvm --name "$VMNAME" --ostype "$VMOSTYPE" --register

# VirtualBox CPU and Memory
VBoxManage modifyvm "$VMNAME" --cpus 1 --cpuexecutioncap 80 --memory 2048

# VirtualBox Network
VBoxManage modifyvm "$VMNAME" --nic1 nat \
    --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 \
    --nic3 hostonly --hostonlyadapter3 vboxnet1

# VirtualBox DVD
VBoxManage storagectl "$VMNAME" --name "IDE Controller" \
    --add ide --controller PIIX4 --hostiocache on --bootable on
VBoxManage storageattach "$VMNAME" --storagectl "IDE Controller" \
    --type dvddrive --port 0 --device 0 --medium "$MEDIA"

# VirtualBox HDD
VBoxManage createhd --filename "$VMNAME".vdi --size 20480
VBoxManage storagectl "$VMNAME" --name "SATA Controller" \
    --add sata --controller IntelAHCI --hostiocache on --bootable on
VBoxManage storageattach "$VMNAME" --storagectl "SATA Controller" \
    --type hdd --port 0 --device 0 --medium "$VMNAME.vdi"
```

Comment: Creation of VM <name>.vbox will always be stoed in ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/<name> by default. Creation of devices is always stored in the current directory when VBoxManage is invoked. VBoxManage can't predict which VM will use the newly created device thus it shouldn't save it in any VM's directory. You should create the the hard drive using full pathname. On attach, you will need to provide the full pathname too. Alternatively, switch to the target directory before creating the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks user3088572. When I used to create through the GUI, the VDI was placed with the VM. How/what does the GUI use to determine the location? According to `printenv`, there does not appear to be a environment setting.

Comment: I was about to reply and noticed that you already figured it all out. Kudos and good job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I came up with for others wandering onto this page. First, use `list` for `systemproperties`. That will get you something like:

```
$ VBoxManage list systemproperties
API version:                     4_2
Minimum guest RAM size:          4 Megabytes
Maximum guest RAM size:          2097152 Megabytes
Minimum video RAM size:          1 Megabytes
Maximum video RAM size:          256 Megabytes
Minimum guest CPU count:         1
Maximum guest CPU count:         32
...
Default machine folder:          /home/jwalton/VirtualBox VMs
VRDE auth library:               VBoxAuth
Webservice auth. library:        VBoxAuth
```

Then parse out the `Default machine folder`. The `awk` is used to trim leading white space (you have to be careful because there's whitespace within the path):

```
TPATH=`VBoxManage list systemproperties | grep -i "default machine folder:" \
    | cut -b 24- | awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")}1'`
VMPATH="$TPATH/$VMNAME"
```

Then, modify the HDD creation with:

```
VBoxManage createhd --filename "$VMPATH/$VMNAME.vdi" --size 20480
VBoxManage storagectl "$VMNAME" --name "SATA Controller" \
    --add sata --controller IntelAHCI --hostiocache on --bootable on
VBoxManage storageattach "$VMNAME" --storagectl "SATA Controller" \
    --type hdd --port 0 --device 0 --medium "$VMPATH/$VMNAME.vdi"
```

Comment: +1 For sharing the solution. This is exactly the correct solution to your question. Good job.

Comment: Try `TPATH=$(VBoxManage list systemproperties | sed -n 's/Default machine folder: *//p')`.

Answer (score 0):

I used previously mentioned solution for some time:

```
VBoxManage list systemproperties | grep "Default machine folder"
```

but one day my disk was full so I had to change "default machine folder" to other location.

And my vagrant solution was suddenly unable locate EXISTING disk images!

So I changed it this way:

```
MYPATH=`VBoxManage showvminfo "<machine name>" 2>/dev/null | grep -E "^Config file" | cut -d: -f2 | sed -s 's#^[[:space:]]*##g'`; echo "${MYPATH%/*}"
```

It reads existing machine folder and extracts its path. It still requires common Linux commands (sed, grep, cut). The last "echo" command is bash specific.

It was not perfect: I still has to distinguish between new and/or existing VM machine.
=> I put both solutions together:

- print existing VM machine folder
- when it does not exist, print default location.

Final one-liner (just replace "VM machine name", its there twice!):

```
VMPATH=`VBoxManage showvminfo "VM machine name" 2>/dev/null | grep -E "^Config file" | cut -d: -f2 | sed -s 's#^[[:space:]]*##g'`; VMDEFAULTPATH=`VBoxManage list systemproperties | grep "Default machine folder" | cut -d: -f2 | sed -s 's#^[[:space:]]*##g'`; if [ "$VMPATH" != "" ];then echo "${VMPATH%/*}"; else echo "${VMDEFAULTPATH}/VM machine name"; fi
```